# Find the eigenfunction of a differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjoint-operators, eigenfunctions

I'm very familiar with solving differential equations. I think I'm just struggling with the setup here because I've never done it with operators. I've always just been given the differential equation and told to find the eigenfunctions. In this physics class, I have to setup the differential equation.

Note: $p = -i \frac{d}{dx}$, the momentum operator.

The operator I'm given is $H=x^3p + px^3$
I am told to show it is formally self-adjoint then to find the eigenfunction and show it has purely imaginary eigenvalues.
(The problem says the eigenfunction is $|x|^{-3/2}\exp(\lambda/4x^2)$, but I have to show that is the case, and I'd like to know how to find it myself.)

I think I am likely setting it up wrong. From what I've seen online, you set the ODE equal to $\lambda * x$.

$-x^3 i \frac{d}{dx}
 - i \frac{d}{dx} x^3 = \lambda x$

$-x^3 i \frac{d}{dx} - i3x^2 = \lambda x$

$\frac{d}{dx} + \frac{3}{x} = - \frac{\lambda}{ix^2}$

I figure from here I could separate it, so I wrote d/dx as dy/dx.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{3}{x}- \frac{\lambda}{ix^2}$

$dy = \left(-\frac{3}{x} - \frac{\lambda}{ix^2}\right) dx$

$y = -3\ln|x| + \frac{\lambda}{ix}$

If you e both sides, I got very close

$|x|^{-3}e^{\lambda/xi}$, but this is not exactly right. As I've said many times, I'm pretty sure it is my setup, can anyone guide me on how to set this problem up?

Comment: This is unreadable, put $ around the equations. And \lambda, not llambda.

Comment: Is that better? I've never done that before. I never knew it did that.

Comment: I edited your post to fix the Math expressions. If you want to see, select the option to edit your question, and then look at the changes I made. Also, please make sure that I did not inadvertently change the content of your post.

Comment: **HINT:** $H$ is a linear operator and so you are solving $Hy = \lambda y$. Find the action of $H$ on $y$ and solve. This will slightly change your first step (and all subsequent steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must apply the operator to a function.

$$\left(ix^3\frac d{dx}-i\frac d{dx}x^3\right)y=-2ix^3\frac{dy}{dx}-3ix^2y=\lambda y$$

is a separable equation.

$$\frac{y'}y=i\frac\lambda{4x^3}-\frac3{2x}$$

and

$$y=c x^{3/2}\exp\left(-i\frac\lambda{4x^2}\right)$$

**Credits to @Gregory.**

Comment: This doesn't match OP solution that they are expecting. It looks like you lost a $1/2$ somewhere.

Comment: @Gregory: did you read to the end ? It is likely that $y$ is a squared probability density.

Comment: I read to the end. I think you made a mistake, but rather than just repeat a second answer, maybe you can just double check the algebra to be sure.

$$Hy = -i(x^3 y' +(x^3 y)') =  -ix^2(3 y + 2 x y').$$

Comment: @Gregory: yep, this works, you are right ! My bad in interpreting the operator.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I see where I went wrong now. Thank you for the help!